# setZoomScale not working for UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a Image I am displaying in html in a webview, I am setting the scalesPageToFit to yes  because the image is quite large.. but this is making the image too small I then try to setZoomScale however this dose nothing..

I am hoping someone can help me set it so the Image inside the UIWebView fits the width of the phone abit closer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated heres my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    waffleSwapperWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    waffleSwapperWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    waffleSwapperWebView.opaque = FALSE;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"waffle-swapper" ofType:@"png"];
    [waffleSwapperWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body bgcolor=""white"" width=460><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",path] baseURL:nil];

    [waffleSwapperWebView.scrollView setZoomScale:5.0];
}
```

Comment: Not sure how correct this is, but I have found if I remove **scalesPageToFit** line and change my html to this **[measurementsWebView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=0.5,maximum-scale=3.0'/><body bgcolor=""white"" width=320 height=320><img src=\"file://%@\"></body></html>",path] baseURL:nil];** it scales down the larger image to fit the screen and enables the maximum zoom on the image which works good, assuming the image size of course.

Answer (score 1):

It works in the ViewDidAppear:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [webView.scrollView setZoomScale:1.2 animated:TRUE];
    CGPoint top = webView.scrollView.contentOffset;
    top.y = 0;
    [webView.scrollView setContentOffset:top animated:FALSE];
}
```

Tried doing it in the webViewDidFinishLoad but for some reason it's not displayed yet.